# Gotowebinar webhook creation 400 bad request Invalid callbackUrl

Tags: postman, webhooks, logmein

I'm trying to create a GotoWebinar webhook but I'm getting 400 bad requests each time

this is my callBackUrl function

```
Route::get('g2w/webhook', function(Request $request) {
  return response()->json([
        'success'=>true
  ],200);
});
```

this is my post webhook creation request to `https://api.getgo.com/G2W/rest/v2/webhooks`

```
[
    {
     "callbackUrl":"https://website.com/g2w/webhook/",
     "eventName":"webinar.created",
     "eventVersion":"1.0.0",
     "product":"g2w"
    }
]
```

and always I get this error

```
{
    "timestamp": 1609341614915,
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "com.logmein.webhooks.exceptions.InvalidRequestException",
    "message": "Invalid callbackUrl. callbackUrl not returning 200 OK as response. Please retry after sometime",
    "path": "/v1/webhooks"
}
```

[GotoWebinar webhooks documentation](https://developer.goto.com/GoToWebinarV2/#operation/createWebhooks)

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You callback endpoint needs to accept both GET and POST request. Change the 'g2w/webhook' route to:

```
Route:match(['get', 'post'], 'g2w/webhook', function(Request $request) {
  return response()->json([
        'success'=>true
  ],200);
});
```